Как сделать видео по ширене сайта и что б сохранял раширение при изменении мастштаба
Здравствуйте! Вставляю видео под шапкой навигации сайта, хочу сделать чтоб оно было ровно по шире странице.  Пробовал разное и либо по центру в маленькое, либо выходит за границы и появляется ползунок. При масштабе 100% все норм, при масштабе 140% ползунок появляется.
<div class="video-box">     
                    <video src="video-fon_01 (4).webm" type="video/webm"   preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" playsinline="playsinline" > 

.video-box{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto; 
display: block;
max-height: 100%

}
